# Change Active/Blocked user status by selecting checkboxes in users table in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose, status

i want to select user in table with checkboxes and change their status to Active/Blocked.
I wrote a code which changing the user status but not persistent. When i login again  their status still remaining same before i changed. Can anyone help how to do that?
Here is What U/I should look like :

[image]

Active should change to Block, Block to Active. It would be great if suggested solutions starts from backend smth like that :

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const { Schema, model } = mongoose;
const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String },
    email: { type: String, unique: true},
    password: { type: String },
    status: {type: String, enum:["Active", "Blocked"], default:"Active"},
    token: { type: String },
    lastLogin: { type: Date, default: Date.now},
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
export default model("User", userSchema);
```

Or should i implement only in front end?

Comment: on check of checkbox, call an api -> the frontend sends the checked value may be true/false and update the same in server

Comment: You didn't explain what does "active" and "blocked" mean and if you persist it into a DB or not?

Comment: It is user status, when it is Active user can login and access  rest data when blocked they cant login. And yes i wanted to persist in to DB. i need some help how to implement in Both fe and be way

Comment: Logged in users should be able to block /unblock themselves , blocked users cant log in . thats the main goal